# Is allowing an OTA to install after rooting a good idea?

Tags: ota-update, root-access

I have a rooted phone with the stock ROM/Kernel. I only use the tethering hack outside of the stock ROM. I was prompted with "System Update" this morning. Should I stay away from this update, or would it be ok?  Thanks!

Comment: What version have you got at the moment?

Comment: Android 2.3.4
Baseband EG31
Build EG30

Comment: As-is this is way too subjective and open-ended.  What are your concerns and what information do you need to make the decision?

Comment: If there's upgraded soft/firmware, I'd like to take advantage of it. But I don't want to risk some adverse effect if I update. I already bricked one phone, so I'm extra cautious.

Comment: The worst case scenario I could see is that you would lose root (and therefore your tethering).  You'll have to regain root and re-apply tethering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A system update will most likely un-root your phone, but if all you have is the tethering hack, I would recommend updating, re-rooting, and reinstalling the hack, after making sure the the hack is supported in the next version.